# What would I have to do to get WNA3100v1 drivers on Xubuntu 14.03?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, netgear

As I have no access to ethernet nor native WiFi, I used an external WiFi adapter. In this case, I need it for internet on my Xubuntu computer. What do I do to get it to work?

Comment: There are several versions of this device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` If yours is a v1, please check here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=wna3100

Comment: It is indeed v1. I'll check the guide. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I seem to have approached an issue. This computer has no internet, as the adapter was the only way to get internet. I have no access to a LAN cable long enough to reach the router. Any ideas? I do have a USB to put stuff on, though.

Comment: You can certainly download the ndiswrapper packages and the driver files on the USB but, as my post points out, the result may be disappointing.  Would you like for me to write the procedure as an answer nevertheless?

Comment: Yeah. Can't go back since Xubuntu's already installed, so might as well.

Comment: You could, of course, shop for a better USB wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download these files on to the USB drive: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper-common_1.59-2_all.deb and also, if yours is a 32-bit system: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9_1.59-2_i386.deb Or 64-bit: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9_1.59-2_amd64.deb

Confirm:

```
arch
```

A 32-bit system will report i686; 64-bit will report x86_64.

Also download the driver files at post #89 here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1695036&page=9

Transfer all from the USB to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine. Install the .deb files first:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i ndis*.deb
```

Note and post any errors.

Right-click the Broadcom file and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2_amended
```

If yours is a 32-bit system:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx32.inf
```

If yours is a 64-bit system:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmn43xx64.inf
```

In both cases:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -ma
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Your device should now be working.

Comment: Ran into an error on the last step. Upon doing "sudo modprobe ndiswrapper", it returned "FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found." What's wrong here?

Comment: Alright, resolved it. I had to install ndiswrapper-dkms and dkms. Once I did that, I did the command again to do it, and it worked! I found internet. Only one issue... It's stuck on the connection process. Is there a way to fix that? I found my internet and it's just stuck trying to connect.

Comment: Resolved that issue now, but I now have another issue again. I can connect to the internet, but can't actually use it. And I can't connect to internet with a password. Been trying to make a bash file to do a series of commands that seemed to make the driver work, but I'm having trouble making it.

Comment: Alright. Something weird happened. So, my internet worked, so I went to go post here, and I came back and I got locked out for a little bit. No biggie. I log back in and it suddenly doesn't work. So, it seems to hiccup a lot. If there's a way to fix the hiccups and issues with trying to connect, because I tried to connect about 10 times before it actually did work, but now it's failing to, it'd be great.

Comment: Please check the link I gave above where I said, "After about an hour, it slowed and stopped. Even though it appeared to be connected, pings to my router or to the DNS nameserver 8.8.8.8 went unanswered." and also: "I don't believe this device can be made to work correctly in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. " Also, above, I suggested that you shop for a better device. I am sorry that I haven't a solution for this exact device.

Comment: It's alright. You tried. I'm using the internet on it right now, and this is the third time I got it to work. It's probably about to go out in 5 minutes, but it's alright. Thanks anyways.